# Custom PopUp menu icon not being displayed on using proguard

Tags: java, android, popup, proguard

I have implemented custom pop-up menu with icon for one of my android app. Here I'm setting the icon also applied `setForceShowIcon`. Here's the following code

```
 final PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(mContext, shareFeed);
            popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.custom_share_menu);
            Object menuHelper;
            Class[] argTypes;
            Field fMenuHelper = null;
            try {
                fMenuHelper = PopupMenu.class.getDeclaredField("mPopup");
                fMenuHelper.setAccessible(true);
                menuHelper = fMenuHelper.get(popupMenu);
                argTypes = new Class[]{boolean.class};
                menuHelper.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setForceShowIcon", argTypes).invoke(menuHelper, true);
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            final String des = map.get("title") + "\n" + map.get("description");
            final String message = Html.fromHtml(des).toString() + "\n" + mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.app_url);
            popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.whatsapp:
                            if (PerformCommonOps.internetConnection(mContext))
                                PerformCommonOps.shareFeedsOnWhatsapp(mContext, message);
                            else
                                Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, "Please ensure you have a working internet connection", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return true;
                        case R.id.facebook:
                            if (PerformCommonOps.internetConnection(mContext))
                                PerformCommonOps.shareToFacebbok(mContext, mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.app_url), view, (Activity) mContext);
                            else
                                Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, "Please ensure you have a working internet connection", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return true;
                        case R.id.text:
                            if (PerformCommonOps.internetConnection(mContext))
                                PerformCommonOps.sendText(mContext, message);
                            else
                                Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, "Please ensure you have a working internet connection", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return true;
                        case R.id.googleplus:
                            if (PerformCommonOps.internetConnection(mContext))
                                PerformCommonOps.shareOnGooglePlus(mContext, Html.fromHtml(des).toString(), mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.app_url), view);
                            else
                                Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, "Please ensure you have a working internet connection", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return true;
                        default:
                            common();
                            return true;
                    }

                }
            });
            popupMenu.show();
```

The icon is being shown when I'm running the app in **Debug mode** but in **Release mode** with **Proguard** the icon is not being displayed. 
Here's my proguard configuration for `setForceShowIcon`

```
######################################
####### POPUpMenu configurations######
######################################
 -keepclassmembernames class android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu { private android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper mPopup; }
 -keepclassmembernames class android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper { public void setForceShowIcon(boolean); }
```

Please let me know where & what I'm doing wrong. **TIA**

Comment: Did you solve this? I too strongly suspect like explained in answer below this is related to proguard setting. But not sure exactly which class shall I specify to keep.

Comment: Same here couldn't find a legit solution

Answer (score 1):

Since `setForceShowIcon` is member of `android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper` I, in general, added these lines to my proguard-rules and it worked very well:

```
-keep class * extends android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keepclassmembernames class * extends android.support.v7.** { *; }
```

Answer (score 1):

This line in `proguard-rules.pro` solve my problem:

`-keep class android.support.v7.widget.** { *; }`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using reflection in your custom popup class you need to avoid it from proguard.

```
-keep public class * extends com.yoursite.android.yourappname.YourClassName

-keepclassmembers class * extends com.yoursite.android.yourappname.YourClassName{
 public <init>(android.content.Context);
}
```

Comment: I'm using the above code in an adapter hence I'm not really extending any class. Can you please explain your solution above

Comment: I mean you need to make a custom class extending PopupMenu and avoid it from using the above code.

Comment: But my proguard settings does the same. Doesn't they?!

Comment: yea but if you are using the PopupMenu inside adapter, then it will get ofescated right. So the reflection code also will get affect. So create your own Custom class extending PopupMenu and put the reflection code inside that. Then try the above one.

Comment: But according to my pro-guard settings, it keeps all the files that uses the private class